# Choice of backend?

Tags: android, ios, node.js, google-app-engine

I'm making my first backend for an app that should work for android and iphone. It should have features similar to instagram with some photos and text.

Currently I'm looking at doing it with google App engine. 
For a backend like this, with users, posts, comments etc. Should I use the datastore option or SQL?

I know JAVA so using google app engine should be fairly simple. But is it simple to make it work with iOS too?

I'm open for suggestions if you think there are better places to do backends like something with node.js or so. It should be easy to deply, quick and expandable.

What would be your suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[parse.com](https://parse.com/) is the answer to all your problems

Comment: very weird .... the moment I wrote about it, servers went down, for the first time in my life, and they've never been down for ages, now they're down for more than half an hour now ... such a weird coincidence

Comment: I was wondering about that. But you say its the first time you experienced it? Because I created an account and 30 min later down. Wasn't much of a first experience.

Comment: yeah it never happened before, yesterday was the first time it went down for 2 hours lol Nonetheless, they're still the best I've seen

Answer (score 1):

At work we use Drupal as a backend.
It's an easy to use CMS, It has secure RESTful connection for doing content management things. It has an iOS SDK https://github.com/workhabitinc/drupal-ios-sdk. It supports commenting, user registration, user permissions, posts out of the box.